# Git скопировать одну папку в другую ветку

Tags: git, github, git-branch

У меня есть 2 ветки main и dev.
В ветке dev несколько файлов: gulpfile.js, package.json и папка app.
Я хочу скопировать из ветки dev в ветку main только содержимое папки app и все.
Не подскажите как можно это сделать?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Существует несколько способов, выбор зависит от того, в каком виде вы хотите получить дерево истории.

Способ №1: Переключиться на ветку dev, скопировать папку app куда-нибудь вне репозитория, переключиться на master, скопировать app обратно, выполнить commit с комментарием типа "актуализация master из dev". В дереве истории никакой связи между dev и master не появится.

Способ №2: Переключиться на ветку master, выполнить merge ветки dev с ключом --no-commit, вручную откатить изменение всех файлов вне папки app, выполнить commit. В дереве истории вы получите коммит слияния с нужным содержимым.

Способ №3: Интерактивный rebase из dev в master только тех коммитов, что меняли папку app. Не рекомендуется для новичков. И сама ветка dev заранее должна была вестись разработчиком с высокой культурой использования git.